# Wordpress redirecionando home para localhost

Tags: wordpress

Fiz a instalação do wordpress no meu localhost para testes, depois tentei migrar para um domínio, fiz as alterações em siteurl e home e atualizei também os links dos posts que tinha, está tudo funcionando corretamente com exceção da pagina home que deveria carregar em meudominio.com.br/ porem está redirecionando para localhost. As outras paginas estão tudo funcionando, por exemplo se eu acessar meudominio.com.br/quemsomos ele carrega normal, o admin também está normal.

Comment: O Search-Replace-DB permite procurar e substituir uma string por outra na base de dados. Tenta utilizar para encontrar e subtituir todos os links do localhost para meudominio.com.br https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Comment: Utilizei o Search-Replace-DB e ele não encontrou nenhuma referencia a localhost, não conheço bem a estrutura do wordpress, não sei se ele salva algo em arquivo.

Comment: Vê se tem alguma referência ao ip 127.0.0.1. Esse endereço equivale a `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Vai em configurações > geral e altera os campos:

Endereço do WordPress (URL) e
Endereço do site (URL)